# FabricTransientException: Could not ping any of the provided Service Fabric gateway endpoints

Tags: c#, iis, azure-service-fabric

Case 1: running my IIS application pool indentity as a user on our corporate domain that has admin priv on my local machine

When the following code runs I get back an exception:

> FabricTransientException: Could not ping any of the provided Service
>   Fabric gateway endpoints.

```
             var c = new FabricClient(creds, "xxxxx.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000");
             ApplicationList applicationList = await c.QueryManager.GetApplicationListAsync(applicationName).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The most inner exception is Exception from

> HRESULT: 0x80071C49 Stack trace:
>
> at
>   System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient.IFabricQueryClient9.EndGetApplicationList2(IFabricAsyncOperationContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricClient.QueryClient.GetApplicationListAsyncEndWrapper(IFabricAsyncOperationContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext
>   context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)

Case 2: running my iss app as LocalSystem the above code works fine and it connects to the fabric uri with no issue.

The certificate is accessible by my local user in case 1. Any idea why I cannot connect as a user vs localSystem?

Comment: what are the creds listed? would that vary with the pool identity?

Comment: cred are same in both cases.  private static X509Credentials GetCredentials()
        {
            var creds = new X509Credentials();

            creds.StoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
            creds.StoreName = "My";
            creds.FindType = X509FindType.FindByThumbprint;
            creds.FindValue = "xxx";
            creds.RemoteCommonNames.Add("www.xxxxx.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com");
            creds.RemoteCertThumbprints.Add("xxxxxx");
            creds.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
            return creds;
        }

Comment: I got past this issue. . Changed my app pool to run as my corporate user and then use pass through on the web service. Before I was running app pool as applicationPoolIndentity and the web service as my corporate user.